# Launching windows metro app from secondary pinned tile

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, live-tile, launching-application

I am developing windows metro app using xaml/C#.
I have following functions for handling app states in App.xaml.cs file :

```
 public overide OnLaunching();  
 public OnSuspending();  
 public OnResuming();
```

I have pinned some app content as secondary tile.
First I launch my app.Then I put it in background
When the launched app goes in suspended state, I click the pinned tile , I am not sure which of OnResuming or onLaunching should be invoked in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear documentation about application lifecycle: [Application lifecycle (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx).
If your app will be in background, it will be `Resumed`, if not - `Launched`. It's easy to check.

> An app is launched whenever it is activated by the user but the
>   process is in the NotRunning state, because it was just deployed, it
>   crashed, or it was suspended but could not be kept in memory.

It also depends on the time, how long your app was in background. Windows Store app have a grace period about 10 seconds, when your app will be kept in memory without suspension.

You should check the `PreviousExecutionState` property to be sure what happened.

Comment: I know the app life cycle. My problem is that I need tile activation arguments for processing the pinned tile . I cant check app log files in my project. I just want to know which of the two OnLaunched() and OnResuming() should be invoked in this case ?
What did you mean by " it will be Resumed, if not - Launched" ??

Comment: Why you need it? You should check the arguments in the OnNavigatedTo method. Arguments is not a scope of Launch or Activate functions.

Comment: onLaunched(args) :
args.Arguments tell me whether the app was launched normally or from pinned tile. I have separate things to do in both the cases.
OnResuming is invoked if app is resumed from suspended state.
If I click the tile when the app is suspended, I want to perform some action by using tile arguments.